# Error in actionscript code: 1000(Ambiguous reference to Button)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a Button Component on my Stage.

When I go to compile I get the following error.

```
1000(Ambiguous reference to Button)
```

Cant seem to find what is wrong here.

Comment: Do you have more than one button in the stage? code could be helpful...

Comment: Yes I do have more than one button. And the code simply is var correctButton:Button; correctButton = button1. button1 is the instance name.+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have more than one class with the name `Button` in your library or in your classpath. The compiler doesn't know which one you want to use and hence the error. Sometimes it helps to provide the full package name like this:

```
var button:com.whatever.buttons.Button = button1;
```

But it's hard to tell if you're not providing some more code.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten that I link to a .swc file earlier than had the button namespace in it. All fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, also consider whether you are mixing access modifiers. For example, on a getter and setter method:

```
public set myVar(a:String):void {
  _a = a;
}

private get myVar():String {
  return _a;
}

public function test():void {
  trace(a); // throws error, though it may not seem obvious why
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue too. I tried declaring the package along with the variable type, but it didn't help. What ended up being the problem was that I had added an mx button while in design mode, but in the script I was declaring a spark.components.button. Once I switched the button type from design mode, it fixed to problem.

```
            for each (var player:XML in rosterFile.player){

                        ...

                var plusB:Button = new Button();
                plusB.id = "plus" + count.toString();
                plusB.x = 286;
                if(count == 0){
                    plusB.y = 37;
                }else{
                    plusB.y = (37 + (count * 64));
                }
                plusB.label = "+";
                arena.addElement(plusB);

                count++;
            }
```